# ¿Como introducir fechas con el comando input?

Tags: python

soy nuevo en programación y no se como poner fechas mediante el teclado (input) para posteriormente sumarle un día. Este es mi código, ya le suma un día a la fecha, pero me falta ponerla con el comando input

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
s = '2019/09/30'
date = date.strptime(s, "%Y/%m/%d")

modified_date = date + timedelta(days=1)
print("la fecha siguiente es", modified_date)
```

Comment: La función `input()` te devuelve siempre una cadena. No puede devolver ningún otro tipo. Pero después puedes convertir la cadena a fecha tal como has hecho en tu código con `date.strptime()`. Con tal de que el usuario haya introducido el texto en el formato correcto (año/mes/dia), la conversión tendrá éxito. Si no tiene ese formato, se generará una excepción.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes hacer una funcion para comprobar si es una fecha, algo asi podrías hacer:

```
def comprobar_fecha(text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(text, '%Y/%m/%d')
    except:
        return "El formato debe ser  YYYY/MM/DD"
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(text, '%Y/%m/%d')

fecha = input("Dame una fecha")

comprobar_fecha(fecha)
```

Si por ejemplo haces esto..

```
fecha="2019/10/03"
fecha_validada = comprobar_fecha(fecha) 
print (str(fecha_validada  + timedelta(days=1)))

>> 2019-10-04 00:00:00
```